Uploading Images from Android App to Backend with Missing EXIF Data
I'm working on an Android application where users can select multiple photos from their device's gallery and upload them to a backend server. To achieve this, I'm using PickMultipleVisualMedia() to get URIs of the selected images and then passing them to a worker for uploading.
Here's how I've implemented the photo picker and the worker:
Photo Picker Implementation:
private fun launchNewPhotoPicker(){
    newPicker.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
}

val newPicker = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(5)) { uris ->
    if (uris != null) {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "Selected URIs: ${uris}")
        runUploadImageWorker(uris)
    } else {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
    }
}

private fun runUploadImageWorker(uris: List<Uri>) {
    val strUris = uris.map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray()
    val data = Data.Builder()
        .putStringArray("uris", strUris)
        .build()

    val uploadImageRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploadImageWorker>()
        .setInputData(data)
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).enqueue(uploadImageRequest)
}

Worker Implementation:
class UploadImageWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val uris = inputData.getStringArray("uris") ?: return Result.failure()

        val client = okhttp3.OkHttpClient()

        for (uriString in uris) {
            val uri = Uri.parse(uriString)
            val inputStream = applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val requestBody = inputStream?.readBytes()?.toRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val body = requestBody?.let {
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), it)
            } ?: return Result.failure()

            val multipartBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addPart(body)
                .build()

            val request = okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url("https://mywonderfullfakeurl.com/api/pictures")
                .post(multipartBody)
                .build()

            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                val errorBody = response.body?.string() ?: "Unknown error"
                Log.d("error", errorBody)
                return Result.failure()
            }
        }

        return Result.success()
    }
}

However, I've noticed that the images uploaded to my backend server are missing EXIF data. How can I ensure that the EXIF data is preserved when uploading images from an Android app using Kotlin?

You dont have to upload first and then later at your server discover that location information  is missing. Better just try to read exif info opening the obtained uri yourself.

I totally agree with your suggestion. However, I'm facing challenges retrieving the EXIF data from the URI within my app. Whenever I attempt to use the EXIF interface to read the data, I encounter an 'ENOENT' (No such file or directory) error. Could you provide guidance or a code snippet on how to correctly retrieve EXIF information from a URI without running into this error?

I've already tested the Maveňツ approach, and as you said, it didn't work. I'll look into alternative methods to accomplish this. And then update this question

Use the Maven approach. You have to change only a little bit to make it work. Just find out where exactly it goes wrong.

To preserve EXIF data when uploading images from an Android app using Kotlin, you can use the following technique, inspired by @Maveňツ, along with using a temporary file to avoid ENOENT errors.
Additionally, as @blackapps pointed out, using OpenMultipleDocuments() instead of PickMultipleVisualMedia() is crucial to prevent null EXIF data when reading from the URI.
Photo Picker Implementation:
    private fun launchNewPhotoPicker(){
        newPiker.launch(arrayOf("image/jpeg"))
    }
 
    private val newPiker=registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenMultipleDocuments()) { uris ->
        if (uris != null) {
            Log.d("PhotoPicker", "Selected URI: ${uris}")
            //launch the worker to upload the images
            runUploadImageWorker(uris)
        } else {
            Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
        }
    }

Worker Implementation:
override fun doWork(): Result {
    val uris = inputData.getStringArray("uris") ?: return Result.failure()

    val client = okhttp3.OkHttpClient()

    for (uriString in uris) {
        val uri = Uri.parse(uriString)
        // create temp file
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val file = File(applicationContext.cacheDir, uuid)
        // copy selected file to temp file
        uri?.let { applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(it) }.use { input ->
            file.outputStream().use { output ->
                input?.copyTo(output)
            }
        }

        val inputStream = file.inputStream()
        val requestBody = inputStream.readBytes().toRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val body = requestBody.let {
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), it)
        }

        val multipartBodyBuilder = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addPart(body)

        // Preserving EXIF data
        val exifInterface = ExifInterface(file)
        val tagsToCheck = arrayOf(
            ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME,
            ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE,
            ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE,
            ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE
        )

        for (tag in tagsToCheck) {
            exifInterface.getAttribute(tag)?.let {
                multipartBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("exif_$tag", it)
            }
        }

        val multipartBody = multipartBodyBuilder.build()
        // don't forget to delete the temporary file
        file.delete()

        val request = okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url("https://mywonderfullfakeurl.com/api/pictures")
            .post(multipartBody)
            .build()

        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

        if (!response.isSuccessful) {
            val errorBody = response.body?.string() ?: "Unknown error"
            Log.d("error", errorBody)
            return Result.failure()
        }
    }

    return Result.success()
}

In this revised version:

We use OpenMultipleDocuments() instead of PickMultipleVisualMedia() to have EXIF data
We use a temporary file to avoid ERNO errors.
EXIF data is preserved by reading it from the temporary file using ExifInterface.
The EXIF data attributes are added to the MultipartBody using addFormDataPart.

This ensures that the uploaded images preserve their selected EXIF data when sent to the backend server.

Even if you implement ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION the provider you get with PickVisualMedia() and PickMultipleVisualMedia() will redact out all exif location information.
This is a feature ;-).
You better use OpenDocument() or OpenMultipleDocuments().

I'll give OpenDocument() a try and see if that resolves the issue.
